# change color of searchview back button

Tags: android, android-studio, optionmenu

I have a searchView in an option menu and this is my xml code for this menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/app_bar_search" android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="search" app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/garden" android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_florist_green_24dp" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="app" app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/about" android:icon="@drawable/ic__ionicons_svg_ios_information_green_circle" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="دabout us" app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

How can I change the color of back button in searchView?
I don't use toolbar and the activities theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light".

Answer (score 0):

One Way is to create a custom appBar with a `SearchView` and style it like this:

```
  <style name="CustomSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name ="voiceIcon">@drawable/ic_flag</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/DarkYellow</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/MainYellow</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">-15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textCapWords</item>
</style>
```

and in your `SearchView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/top_search_bar"
    style="@style/CustomSearchViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on res>new>Vector Asset 
[image]

Asset Studio dialog box will open.
Click on Button next to Clip Art.
[image]`

Choose any icon. In this case arrow back.
Click on color and choose any desired color you want
Name the icon. Note that this name you will use to reference in your xml. In this case `ic_arrow_back_yellow`
[image]

Click next and Finish. By default it will be saved in drawable.

Now in your xml reference your added icon `@drawable/ic_arrow_back_yellow`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/app_bar_search" android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_yellow" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="search" app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/garden" android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_florist_green_24dp" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="app" app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/about" android:icon="@drawable/ic__ionicons_svg_ios_information_green_circle" android:orderInCategory="101" android:title="دabout us" app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: no, I want to change back button icon, but your code changes the icon of searchView.

Comment: Search for the back button from the assets. Arrow back icon can be used for back button